# GridView edit button cause exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, button, edit

I have a command template for `delete` and `edit` button.

When I click the `edit` button and fill in data of correct datatype for each field, this will work just fine.

However, when I fill in data of wrong datatype into the fields, an exception will trigger on web page browser. How can I to rectify this, any code behind you guys can suggest, and where to put it?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ProductCode" DataSourceID="SqlProductmaster" 
                    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductCode" HeaderText="ProductCode" 
                            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductCode" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" 
                            SortExpression="ProductName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" 
                            SortExpression="Category" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SellingPrice" HeaderText="SellingPrice" 
                            SortExpression="SellingPrice" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" 
                            SortExpression="Quantity" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="BrandName" HeaderText="BrandName" 
                            SortExpression="BrandName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReOrderQty" HeaderText="ReOrderQty" 
                            SortExpression="ReOrderQty" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReOrderLevel" HeaderText="ReOrderLevel" 
                            SortExpression="ReOrderLevel" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Ordered" HeaderText="Ordered" 
                            SortExpression="Ordered" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Allocated" HeaderText="Allocated" 
                            SortExpression="Allocated" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FreeQty" HeaderText="FreeQty" 
                            SortExpression="FreeQty" />
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Update" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                                    CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                                &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Cancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                    CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="edit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                    CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                    CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Navy" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="White" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What is the exception name? Maybe you need to write an event.

Comment: @Marco Sorry Marco, now the exception gone, but other problem arise. Seems like update button not triggering anything when i clicked.cancel and delete work fine. Weird?

Comment: it's more a problem in your code-behind, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

you can put validation for that particular control and never exception generated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using template fields, you can override functions which allow you to edit BoundFields. To do this, try something like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvCurrentLocations" ... OnRowEditing="rowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="rowCancel" OnRowUpdating="rowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="locationname" HeaderText="Location Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbToRemove" runat="server" CssClass="remove" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="boundpdas" HeaderText="Assigned To" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" UpdateText="Save"  />
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        There are currently no locations.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Notice how the 2nd bound field is readonly, this will prevent it being editable. The command field in the 4th column exposes a button 'Edit' which changes the bound field to a text box.

In your backend code, you can get the new values by accessing the 'NewValues' dictionary of the GridViewUpdateEventArgs parameter.